# Use V-IF to show button only when a value from Firestore is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading documents from firestore database and loading them into cards. I want the card to include buttons when a value in the object loaded is true.

```
{ "Alarm": false, "Safety": true, "Battery": true }.
```

So for this example I would like to load a battery button and a safety button but not an alarm button.

I am using v-if and a created function and cannot seem to get it working any way that I try.

When I load the documents they get put into an array (users) and I have no problem reading them.

I have seen many articles online and when I try and replicate how they did it, nothing works. I used just a i.e. `v-if=(users.Alarm)` and I have tried using a created function and a few variations of the two.

```
 <v-card  class="mx-4 grey darken-4" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">

     <v-footer flat height="35px"  color="black"> 
       <v-btn class="green--text mx-1" x-small v-if="safety">Safety</v-btn> 

       <v-btn class="red--text mx-1" x-small v-if="alarm">Alarm</v-btn> 

       <v-btn class="yellow--text mx-1" x-small v-if="battery">Battery</v-btn> 

     </v-footer>
     <v-divider></v-divider>
</v-card>

export default {
  components: {  },
  data() {

    return {
      safety: false,
      battery: false,
      alarm: false,
      users: [],
    };
  },

  created() { 
    if (users.Safety) {
       this.check = true;

   }},
// here goes the other buttons once I get one working


   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   var SuperUser = user.uid + "3329"

    db.collection(SuperUser)

      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {

            id: doc.id,
            Safety: doc.data().Safety,
            Alarm: doc.data().Alarm,
            Battery: doc.data().Battery,

          };

          this.users.push(data);
        });
      })
     }
    };
```

I want to only show the buttons in the card when their values are true. They are set to Boolean in the database. If true =  show button else don't show. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `users` is an array, it won't have a property `users.Alarm`. If there are several users in the array then which one should it use? To use the first user it would be `users[0].Alarm`, though it seems unlikely that's really what you'd want here. Perhaps there is a `v-for` on the `users` that you haven't shown?

Comment: Yes, I was using a v-for earlier in the code and left it out on accident.                                 <v-card  class="mx-4 grey darken-4" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">

Comment: So you've tried `v-if="user.Alarm"`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple and I just had a small mistake, I used users.Alarm instead of user.Alarm. From the v-for. Thanks for your answers though it helped me figure out what I did wrong. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the relevant data after getting the API response. I think you should set `safety`, `battery` and `alarm` value in callback. like this ..

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data = {
        id: doc.id,
        Safety: doc.data().Safety,
        Alarm: doc.data().Alarm,
        Battery: doc.data().Battery,
      };
       this.users.push(data);
       this.safety = doc.data().Safety;
       this.battery = doc.data().Battery;
       this.alarm = doc.data().Alarm;

    });
```

Comment: I use the same data elsewhere and the data is loaded fine. It can display exactly what the database has in it.

Comment: It should not work in any way. you set the value in user object and use other data (safety, alarm...)  in `v-if` . Either you have to set values (safety, alarm...) in your callback or you have to use `user.Safety`, `user.Alarm ` or `user.Battery ` in `v-if`